# Can I copy/paste code all at once?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to copy and paste the code from the link below.

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Increase the cell size of the merged cells to highlight the formatting.
worksheet.set_column('B:D', 12)
worksheet.set_row(3, 30)
worksheet.set_row(6, 30)
worksheet.set_row(7, 30)


# Create a format to use in the merged range.
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'border': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': 'yellow'})


# Merge 3 cells.
worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4', 'Merged Range', merge_format)

# Merge 3 cells over two rows.
worksheet.merge_range('B7:D8', 'Merged Range', merge_format)


workbook.close()
```

When I copy/paste the script into Python 2.7.12 Shell, as a whole, nothing happens at all.  There is no error and nothing is done.  If I copy/paste each line, and run each one at a time, it works fine.

How can I setup my environment so I can copy/paste several lines of code and run everything all at once?

Thanks.

Here is an image from my Window Start Button.

[image]

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your terminal emulator, it's not translating the newlines in the paste correctly.

Comment: It works fine for me using the OS X Terminal.

Comment: You can copy and paste into a file and run that. Or setup Jupyter notebooks so you have cells that can run independently

Comment: the ConEmu shell will let you copy-n-paste multiple lines, but learn to put your code in a file and run the file instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can paste it as one long string and `exec` it.

```
exec('''#paste code here,
#as many lines as you want
''')
```